# 3D rigid body transform decomposition reorder

Tags: math, image-processing, linear-algebra

I have this idea in my head and I am trying to figure out how to implement it. One of the parts that I am struggling with is how to take a 3D rigid-body transform and decompose it into ***dx, dy, dz, theta_X, theta_Y, and theta_Z***.

This of course is a very well document algorithm. My problem is that matrix algebra is noncommutative. I would like to reorder the components such that it goes ***(dx*dy*theta_Z)*(dz*theta_X*theta_Y)***.

For any of you who wants to know why I want to do this is because I would like to do apply the transform ***(dx*dy*theta_Z)*** on a 3D image followed by then another operation followed by the completion of the rigid body transform. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right you want to isolate XY plane transform separately from a 3D transform that is possible only if the `theta_Z` rotation is applied first (as you want it to be first). If not then you would need to convert your order of Euler angles first for example with this:

- [Is there a way to calculate 3D rotation on X and Y axis from a 4x4 matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56950130/2521214)

If you do not know the translations you can obtain them directly from matrix see:

- [Understanding 4x4 homogenous transform matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214)

now its just a matter of using the translations in corect coordinate system (depends on order of your transformations)

As you did not provide any specific data nor MCVE I can not go in more details as there are quite a few combinations of possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

If you first decompose your rotation into your desired ordering (`theta_Z * theta_X * theta_Y`), it is reasonably straightforward to reorder any translation the way you want:

```
let:   t' = theta_Z^-1 * t * theta_Z

then:  t * theta_Z = theta_Z * t' 

and:   t * theta_Z * theta_X * theta_Y
     = theta_Z * t' * theta_X * theta_Y
```

However, for the particular reordering you want, please note that rotation about the Z axis should not affect a pure translation about the Z axis at all!  Even though general rigid body transforms don't commute, your `dz` and `theta_Z` transforms do:

```
commutative:  dz * theta_Z = theta_Z * dz

and:  my_transform = dx * dy * dz * theta_Z * theta_X * theta_Y
                   = dx * dy * theta_Z * dz * theta_X * theta_Y
```