# how do I get rotations of each axis from rotations with a vector axis?

Tags: graphics

so I have an AxisAngle4f object with a vector3D as axis and an angle, how do I get rotation angle for each of x,y,z axes?

Comment: I updated my answer with some more code and "easier" obtaining of the `M`

Answer (score 0):

1. **create 4x4 homogenous transform matrix representing your rotation**

   first see [Understanding 4x4 homogenous transform matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214) so basically you want 3 basis vectors and origin of unit matrix then rotate each by your rotation (for that you can use this or `glRotate` or whatever). Here C++ example:

   ```cpp
   void rotate3d(float alfa,float *axis,float *point)
        {
        float p[3],q[3],c=cos(alfa),s=sin(alfa);
        //Euler Rodrigues' rotation formula
        vector_mul(q,point,c);
        vector_mul(p,axis,point);
        vector_mul(p,p,s);
        vector_add(p,p,q);
        vector_mul(q,axis,vector_mul(axis,point)*(1.0-c));
        vector_add(point,p,q);
        }
   ```

   The vector math functions are described (with source) in the link above. Just change the `double` into `float` as you are using those. So it boils up to something like this in C++:

   ```cpp
   float X[3] = { 1.0,0.0,0.0 };
   float Y[3] = { 0.0,1.0,0.0 };
   float Z[3] = { 0.0,0.0,1.0 };
   float O[3] = { 0.0,0.0,0.0 };
   float M[16];
   float AxisAngle4f[4]={x,y,z,angle};
   rotate3d(AxisAngle4f[3],AxisAngle4f,X);
   rotate3d(AxisAngle4f[3],AxisAngle4f,Y);
   rotate3d(AxisAngle4f[3],AxisAngle4f,Z);
   rotate3d(AxisAngle4f[3],AxisAngle4f,O);
   M[0]=X[0]; M[4]=Y[0]; M[ 8]=Z[0]; M[12]=O[0];
   M[1]=X[1]; M[5]=Y[1]; M[ 9]=Z[1]; M[13]=O[1];
   M[2]=X[2]; M[6]=Y[2]; M[10]=Z[2]; M[14]=O[2];
   M[3]= 0.0; M[7]= 0.0; M[11]= 0.0; M[15]= 1.0;
   ```

   Where `M` is OpenGL style direct matrix representing your rotation.
2. **convert `M` into your Euler angles**

   see [Is there a way to calculate 3D rotation on X and Y axis from a 4x4 matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56950130/2521214) on how (again change to `floats`)...

   ```cpp
   const float deg=M_PI/180.0;
   const float rad=180.0/M_PI;
   // variables
   float e[3],m[16];
   int euler_cfg[_euler_cfgs];
   // init angles
   e[0]=10.0*deg;
   e[1]=20.0*deg;
   e[2]=30.0*deg;
   // compute coresponding rotation matrix with your environment
   m = some_rotate_of yours(e)
   // cross match e,m -> euler_cfg
   matrix2euler_init(e,m,euler_cfg);

   // now we can convert M into e
   matrix2euler(e,M,euler_cfg);
   // e holds your euler angles you want
   ```

   The init of `euler_cfg` is needed just once then you can use `matrix2euler` at will.