# How to get a forward, Right and Up vector from JUST Euler Angles No quaternions or Matrices

Tags: math, vector

Is it possible, To get a Forward, Right and Up Directional Vectors just from Euler Angles, no quaternions or Matrices. I don't mind if it is slower, how fast the code is isn't my main goal. I've been wrapping my head about quaternions and Matrices for 2 weeks, and it didn't work, when I came here I got a response that didn't event work or gave any useful information. I know there is a huge ton of questions like this But I searched over all possible sites and the answer was always to use Quaternions or Matrices, so is it even possible ?

Answer (score 0):

In 3D To transform vector without [matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214) You just rewrite the `matrix*vector` operation

```
(x',y',z') = M*(x,y,z)
```

into:

```
x' = m[0][0]*x + m[0][1]*y + m[0][2]*z;
y' = m[1][0]*x + m[1][1]*y + m[1][2]*z;
z' = m[2][0]*x + m[2][1]*y + m[2][2]*z;
```

where the matrix `m[row][col]` is (just 3x3 rotational part) result of 3 axis aligned rotation matrices:

[image: 3D rotation matrices]

multiplied together in order you use (algebraicaly as equations you can do this in any math SW like Derive for Windows if you too lazy like me) for example:

[image: euler angles XYZ matrix]

Both images where taken from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) so for example

```
m[0][0]=(cos(a)*cos(b))
m[0][1]=((cos(a)*sin(b)*sin(c))-(sin(a)*cos(c)))
m[0][2]=((cos(a)*sin(b)*cos(c))-(sin(a)*sin(c)))
x' = m[0][0]*x + m[0][1]*y + m[0][2]*z;
-----------------------------------------------------
x' = (cos(a)*cos(b))*x + ((cos(a)*sin(b)*sin(c))-(sin(a)*cos(c)))*y + ((cos(a)*sin(b)*cos(c))-(sin(a)*sin(c)))*z
```

I am too lazy to write the rest (that is one of the reason why matrices are used its more convenient). Also for the sake of speed precompute the `sin` and `cos` values of `a,b,c` angles into variables like `cosa,cosb,cosc,sina,sinb,sinc` and use that instead of calling the same slow goniometric functions again and again so...

```
x' = (cosa*cosb)*x + ((cosa*sinb*sinc)-(sina*cosc))*y + ((cosa*sinb*cosc)-(sina*sinc))*z
```

Now you just use this to transform 3 unit directions `(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)` and the result will be your vectors.

for more info about the topic see:

- [Is there a way to calculate 3D rotation on X and Y axis from a 4x4 matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56950130/2521214) ...